# Looking for veterans of the Space Race

Tags: apollo-program, kennedy-space-center, project-mercury, project-gemini, cape-canaveral

[image: My father with Freedom 7 after it was recovered and returned to Hanger S in May 1961.]

Hi everyone. I am writing an oral history of the men and women who worked at Cape Canaveral and KSC during Mercury, Gemini and Apollo. If you know someone that fits the bill, or know how to find them, please contact me at atlantaproducer@gmail.com.

The picture above is my father posing with Freedom 7 after it was returned to Hanger S. The outer skin had been removed to inspect for scorching.

Comment: Welcome to Space.SE, please be sure to [take the tour](https://space.stackexchange.com/tour)! I'm afraid your question is not a good fit for this site as it's not a question that can be given a definitive "answer" to. StackExchange sites are different to forums. So I'm afraid your question is going to be closed as off-topic. Good luck with your endeavor, though!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not "answerable" in its current form.

Comment: I suggest you may have better luck finding the connections you seek in a more social setting, rather than a Q&A site like this. There is a Space Hipster group on Facebook that contains many collectors of this old information, as well as some former employees.

Comment: I suggest you to do it on your real name. The few people having contact, or oral history, are probably not very glad to write emails to unknown persons. You need to build up trust.

Comment: I can recommend the NasaSpaceflight.com and collectspace.com sites.

Comment: Also have you seen the existing NASA oral history sites? e.g. https://history.nasa.gov/ and do a search for 'NASA oral history' for more